# How to get properties of functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I have functions with two different type signatures:

```
f :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
g :: (Int, Int) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The first parameter determines the length of the list that the function operates on. For example, `f` might operate on lists of length `p-1` and `g` operates on lists of length `p^(e-1)` for first arguments `p` and `(p,e)` respectively.

I use `f` and `g` as arguments to another function `h :: Int -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]` which needs to know this length function (`h`'s first argument). What I find myself doing currently is:

```
\p -> h (p-1) (f p)
\(p,e) -> h (p^(e-1)) (g (p,e))
```

everywhere I use `h` in combination with `f` and `g`. This duplication is error prone and messy.

The goal is to find a way to avoid passing the length argument to `h`. Instead, `h` should be able to determine the length itself based on the function argument.

One non-solution would be to change the definition of `f` to:

```
f' :: (Int, Int) -> [a] -> [a]
f' (2,_) = previous def
f' (p,_) = previous def

funcToLen :: ((Int, Int) -> [a] -> [a]) -> (Int, Int) -> Int
funcToLen f' (p,_) = p-1
funcToLen g (p,e) = p^(e-1)

h' :: (Int, Int) -> ((Int, Int) -> [a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
h' (p,e) func xs = let len = funcToLen func
                       func' = func (p,e)
                   in previous def

-- usage
(\p -> h' (p,??) f')
(\(p,e) -> h' (p,e) g)
```

This has several drawbacks:

- I have to change the first argument of `f`, and then ignore the second part of the tuple
- When I actually use `h'` with `f'`, I have to create a dummy argument for the second part of the tuple
- Most importantly, `funcToLen` doesn't work because I can't pattern match on function names.

Another solution that actually works is to use `Either`:

```
f' :: Int -> (Int, [a] -> [a])
f' 2 xs = (1, previous def)
f' p xs = (p-1, previous def)

g' :: (Int, Int) -> Either Int ([a] -> [a])
g' (p,1) xs = (1, previous def)
g' (p,e) xs = (p^(e-1), previous def)

h' :: (Int, ([a] -> [a])) -> ([a] -> [a])
h' ef = let len = fst ef
            f = snd ef
        in previous def
```

This also has a few downsides:

- The length function is duplicated for each pattern of `f'` and `g'`
- The type signatures of `f'`, `g`', and `h'` are all uglier
- I can't immediately use `f'` and `g'` on their own (i.e. not as arguments to `h'`). Instead I have to peel off the tuple.

I'm looking for ways to clean this up so that I don't have to duplicate the length function everywhere, but also allows me to use the functions `f` and `g'` in the expected way. I expect this problem has been "solved" before, but I don't know quite what I should be looking for.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this messy passing around of "lengths to operate on" anyway? Sounds like it would be much better to split up the list and pass some parts to functions that operate on _all_ the list.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. It's not possible to pattern-match on functions, and in your definition of `funcToLen`, the first pattern would always succeed, and in the second example, you're using `Either` as a constructor (did you mean `Left`/`Right`?) Either way with so many random one-character variables lying around, it's quite difficult to follow. I'm struggling to understand why this would be necessary. Anyway, since you have two different types, and need to pattern match on them, using `Either` seems like the best bet.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In a word, math. The list input is a tensor, and `f` and `g` operate on one dimension of that tensor. The function `h` "lifts" `f` and `g` from one dimension to many dimensions. The result is that `f` and `g` end up working on just a few elements of the list, spaced out by a stride and with an offset. `h` needs to know the dimension of `f` so that it knows how many times (and with what stride/offset) to run `f`.

Comment: I am apparently grossly misusing the `Either`monad. I'll replace those with tuples...

Comment: You use plain lists to represent tensors? That's... audacious. What's wrong with [`Data.Tensor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tensor-0.3.0.1/docs/Data-Tensor.html)? If not something pre-built like that, you should at least wrap up a custom type that properly takes care of dimension issues.

Comment: No, I'm not using plain lists. It's a minimal example, hence why I didn't bring up tensors in the question. I'll check into `Data.Tensor`, thanks for pointing that out. I'm using a custom vector type to handle indexing with tensors, but that's not helping me when I need to iterate a function over multiple indices.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a function `c` that calculates `p^e-1`, effectively decoupling this operation from `f` and `g`:

```
c :: (Int, Int) -> Int
c (p, e) = p ^ (e - 1)
```

you can merge `f` and `g` into the same function (by simply eliminating `g`). When you have to convert a tuple into an `Int`, you use `c`.

The implementation of `h` is also trivial and does not contain duplicated code.

Comment: I can't just get rid of `g`, it does something completely different than `f`. Maybe you could show some more code?